# how to match the pattern if the pattern is abba and there will be given a single string that is "redbluebluered" which matches the pattern

Tags: regex, string-matching

I was in the technical round of a campus drive yesterday and asked to solve this problem. I was not reached close to the solution of this problem and i was rejected from there , now I am still trying to solve this but not able to solve.I am wondering that how to solve this problem.The interviewer says that there will be no space in the test string and also it's a single string.

if there will input String pattern will abba.
then matching patterns will be
1) catdogdogcat
2) redbluebluered
3) noyesyesno

And not matching pattern will be
1) catdogcat
2) redbluered
3) yesnoyes

(sorry for my bad english)

thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be what you're after if you need a generic solution that doesn't use specific words:

```
(\w+)(\w+)\2\1
```

https://regex101.com/r/hP8lA3/1

It's not very efficient but it tries to greedily match two word groups and then uses [backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) to make sure they are followed by the second group first, then the first group.

You could make it even more generic to match two groups of *any* character (besides newline): `(.+)(.+)\2\1`

Here is one possible solution to the full problem using C#:

```
private bool matcher(string pseudoPattern, string text) {
    string regexPattern = "^";
    var uniqueParts = new List<char>();

    foreach (char part in pseudoPattern.ToCharArray())
        if (uniqueParts.Contains(part)) {
            int backReference = uniqueParts.FindIndex(p => p == part) + 1;

            regexPattern += @"\" + backReference;
        }
        else {
            uniqueParts.Add(part);

            regexPattern += @"(\w+)";
        }

    regexPattern += "$";

    var regex = new Regex(regexPattern);

    return regex.Match(text).Success;
}
```

Comment: but there is a problem , that the Interviewer wants program which takes two string, the first one is pattern and the second one is testString.That we can't do it in regular expression because we have different input pattern at every time of execution. Thank you

Comment: @TariqueShamim - is it related to this question, or is that a separate question from the interviewer?

Comment: this is the actual question.

Comment: :- he wants me to create program for checking with more than one pattern and testString.

Comment: @TariqueShamim - What language is it in?  And is 'abba' the actual format of the input pattern?  What are some other examples?

Comment: I was tried to do this in java.There was no actual format he gives some more patterns like abccba,aada and the matching patterns are like dogcatgogocatdog and redredbluered respectively.

Comment: @TariqueShamim - Okay, I updated my answer with one possible solution using C#.  Should be pretty similar in Java.

Comment: Thanks for the program. :)  I was tried to solve this using the horrible brute force and including dynamic programming. RegEx made it so easy enough to solve pattern algorithms using it.